# Thymeleaf: Query String

Tags: query-string, thymeleaf

How to create in Thymeleaf the url:

```
/user/map?userId=1&mapId=2
```

In the thymeleaf model I have access to ${user.id} and ${map.id}.

I have tried:

```
th:href="@{'/user/map/update/?userId=' + ${user.id} + '&mapId=' + ${map.id}}"
```

but it gives:

```
The reference to entity "mapId" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

Comment: You should always encode & to `&amp;` in HTML/XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Thymeleaf url expressions can do this for you.](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)

```
<a th:href="@{/user/map(userId=${user.id},mapId=${map.id})}">
```